# error populating dropdown with value angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When my page loads I prepoulate the dropdown like this

```
 $scope.categories =
                    [
                        0,
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4
                    ];
```

here is my dropdown

```
<div>
                        Category:
                        <select data-ng-model="category.currentCategory"
                                data-ng-options="cat for cat in categories">{{cat}}
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I now have a need to change the drop down value depending on data. so I do this

`$scope.cat = 1` to preselect value of one but that doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

here is the error that I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentCategory' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

For data-ng-model you should have just "category" (you never define the currentCategory attribute on category), and you should set it to $scope.category=1, since that is the model, not $scope.cat. When you say "cat for cat in categories", cat is a local variable that represents that iteration of categories in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="Caty">
   <option ng-repeat="cat in categories">
      {{cat}}
   </option>
</select>
```

To pre-select a value,

```
$scope.Caty = $scope.categories[0];
```

It works.